# Bash exercise giving multiple input to a script by another

Tags: linux, bash

i've come across to another exercise in preparation to the exam that i always find tricky for the redirection of input/output.

it asks:
Write a first script named "contaseparatamente.sh" that takes a variable number of arguments, each is a name of a file.
The script need to **write** on the **Standard output** the tot number of rows of the **even's arguments** and on the **Standard error** the tot number of rows of the **odd's arguments**.
(And i have done like this, and it works):
GNU nano 4.8                                                                               contaseparatamente.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMEVEN=0
NUMODD=0
for((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
        if((i%2==0))
        then
                NUMEVEN=$((${NUMEVEN} + `wc -l ${!i} | cut -d ' ' -f 1` ))
        else
                NUMODD=$((${NUMODD} + `wc -l ${!i} | cut -d ' ' -f 1` ))
        fi;
done
echo rows of even ${NUMEVEN}
echo rows of odd ${NUMODD} 1<&2
```

then it asks: write a second script to launch and execute the first giving him as arguments the first 7 line of the output of `ls -S1 /usr/include/*.h` in the end this second script must show on the standard error also the output of the first script.
This is my try:
GNU nano 4.8

```
#!/bin/bash
./contaseparatamente.sh <( ls -S1 /usr/include/*.h | head -n 7 ) 2<&1
```

but in this way the result is
0 rows from the even
and 7 from the odd, which is not possible

Comment: For the record, I am annoyed this assignment explicitly asks you to parse ls...  but you are feeding the list on stdin instead of as args.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the assignment, but...

To pass the args in the simplest way, use an unquoted subshell. (*ugh*)

```
#!/bin/bash
./contaseparatamente.sh $( ls -S1 /usr/include/*.h | head -n 7 )
```

The stderr of the first script *will* bleed through and show when you run the second script if you do nothing at all. If you need it on stdout, just redirect.

```
#!/bin/bash
./contaseparatamente.sh $( ls -S1 /usr/include/*.h | head -n 7 ) 2>&1
```